# Pinocchio protocol: Is this equation meaning polynomial's dot product or multiplication?

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, snarks

In [Pinocchio paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2013/279.pdf), I'm confused by the equation in section 2.2.1. (image below)

Is the product of two polynomials $v_0(x)+\sum(cv(x))$ and $w_0(x)+\sum(c_w(x))$ of dot product or just a simple multiplication?

[image: image from section 2.2.1]

What I mean by the dot product of two polynomials is the multiplication of same-degree terms in each polynomial. i.e. $(2x^2 + x)*(3x^2 + 2x) = 6x^2 + 2x$ for example.

My guess was it is dot-product. But, according to [this article](https://medium.com/@VitalikButerin/quadratic-arithmetic-programs-from-zero-to-hero-f6d558cea649), it seems to be a simple multiplication!

The reason why I found it counterintuitive is that, if it's a simple multiplication, the relationship that the product of left-wire and right-wire equals to output-wire doesn't hold thus violates an equation $p(x) = h(x)t(x)$.

Can anyone provide me with a justification?

Comment: The only thing that would make sense is polynomial multiplication; for example: $(x+1) \cdot(2x+3) = 2x^2 + 5x + 3$, where the coefficients are over some field $\mathbb{F}$ (presumably finite).  The only caveat would be that the multiplication might be implicitly modulo some other polynomial; I didn't see that from an initial glance through the paper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's regular polynomial multiplication.

For any given gate $g$ we assign a value $r_g$, we set things up so that the condition "left input times right input equals output" is equivalent to the condition $p(r_g)=0$ which in turn is equivalent to $(x-r_g)|p(x)$ so that the correctness of all gates can be checked by $\prod_g(x-r_g)|p(x)$ where the dividend is $t(x)$.

This means that we have to ensure that we choose $v_k(x)$, $w_k(x)$ and $y_k(x)$ so that
$$v_0(r_g)+\sum c_kv_k(r_g)=c_{L_g}, w_0(r_g)+\sum c_kw_k(r_g)=c_{R_g}\quad {\rm and }\quad y_0(r_g)+\sum c_ky_k(r_g)=c_{O_g}$$
where $L_g$ is the index of the left input wire for $g$, $R_g$ is the index of the right input wire for $g$ and $O_g$ is the index for the output wire of $g$. If this is the case then $c_{L_g}c_{R_g}=c_{O_g}\Rightarrow p(r_g)=0$ as required. The value of $p$ at points other than $r_g$ does not directly reveal anything about the correctness of evaluation of $g$. We can achieve the above requirements by specifying that
$$v_k(r_g)=\begin{cases}1 &k=L_g\\ 0 &otherwise\end{cases}$$
$$w_k(r_g)=\begin{cases}1 &k=R_g\\ 0 &otherwise\end{cases}$$
$$y_k(r_g)=\begin{cases}1 &k=O_g\\ 0 &otherwise\end{cases}$$
which passes each polynomial through $m$ points (one for each wire) so that we can construct such polynomials using Lagrange interpolation.

Comment: Thank you for quick and great reply! It now totally makes sense.